# How to create simple Jersey app without using Maven

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, jaxb, jax-rs

I wanted to make a simple Jersey-based REST app without using Maven in NetBeans. I followed the following steps and now I am stuck:

1. Created a simple web app using NetBeans (or any other development IDE).
2. Added JAX-RS libraries to my project.
3. I don't have `web.xml` present since I am using `org.netbeans.rest.application.config`.

I am stuck now. I want to use `web.xml`. Is there any alternative?

P.S. - I am trying to use JSON as input without using Maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since in your third step you've created the configuration class to expose your JAX-RS Resource classes, you don't need the functionality in `web.xml`. Your application should be ready to run, at least on Glassfish or another Java  server.

The whole idea of Java EE 6 is to get rid of XML configuration files like the `web.xml`. New annotations like `@javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet` and `@javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath` are used to configure Servlets and REST applications.

But if you *want* to have a `web.xml`, you can create one in the directory `web/WEB-INF`. A minimal `web.xml` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
</web-app>
```

Comment: Yes, you can do this. I suggest we talk about this in the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java

Comment: dont have enough repo , just a quick query if you can help me here , how can I use json query parameter and store it as json object